# DATAtable issue in C# final data retains

Tags: c#, datatable

In C# i have a list of data tables

```
List<DataTable> AAA= new List<DataTable>();
```

i have a code of the below form

```
DataTable CQ = new DataTable();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 1");
AAA.add(CQ);

....................

CQ.clear();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 2");
AAA.add(CQ);

...........................

....................

CQ.clear();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 3");
AAA.add(CQ);

....................

CQ.clear();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 4");
AAA.add(CQ);
```

Now AAA shd have a list of items with first item having set1 data, 2nd set2 ....4th item set 4.

But the issue is i am getting set 4 data in all the items in the list. Where am i doing mistake

Kindly clarify...

Comment: How about showing your code where you add *multiple* items to list. Do you use same *CQ* ?

Comment: Yes i am using the same CQ and clearing it . as  it is not really required to create new CQs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable is a reference Type [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

So everytime you are updating your `datatable` value it's getting updated in your List.

Answer (score 2):

DataTable is a Reference Type. And you are adding same dataTable again and again.
when you call CQ.clear(); it clears all the rows already inserted in the DataTable.
Currently All Items in the list refer to same DataTable. 
You need to make a New DataTable  every time before adding to the list to achieve your objective

```
DataTable CQ = new DataTable();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 1");
AAA.add(CQ);

....................

CQ = new DataTable();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 2");
AAA.add(CQ);

...........................

....................

CQ = new DataTable();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 3");
AAA.add(CQ);

....................

CQ = new DataTable();

CQ.Rows.Add("Some data----set 4");
AAA.add(CQ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new row and then add into `AAA` otherwise it will add last value.